# What should be there in the blank - "altruistic" or "altruist"?

Tags: word-choice

I was to fill in a blank with proper word alongside its definition which was:

> Unselfish, more interested in the welfare of others than in one's own.

The answer given in the key was - altruistic. But I don't know why I am feeling that there should be "altruist" instead of "altruistic" as the answer because "altruistic" are "tendencies, behaviour". So, "altruistic" can't be used as a noun.

Comment: _Unselfish_ isn't a noun either!

Comment: But "more interested in the welfare of others than in one's own" implies that it is "someone" not "some kind of action or behaviour".

Comment: It can only be an adjective with that definition. For a noun, the definition would have to be something like *a person who is unselfish...*.

Comment: Note that this has already been asked at [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/212602/what-should-be-there-in-the-blank-altruistic-or-altruist#comment407281_212602).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are describing a thing, say a person, [think simple adjective, *blue house* or *fast car*]

You might write:

> His (altru-) behavior

Here the morphology is *altru-ist-ic*.

> His altruistic behavior

- -of or like [-ic; eg **[sophomoric](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sophomoric)**, **pedantic**]
- -a thing or person [-ist; eg **chemist**, **popularist**, **racist**]
- -root [altru; eg Latin **autre** "other"]

---

If you are describing say in a copula/existential/stative way which (employs an article [a/the] in English)

You might write:

> His is a/the[article] (altru-)

Here the morphology is *altru-ist*.

> He is a(n) altruist

---

In your example, either you or the question is omitting context. In your case, how do the other questions tilt. In this question writer's case, "in one's own" kind of invokes the third person, which is subject territory (and you altruist feeling), but "unselfish" is like an adjective, so tilting back in that direction... That's a picky test ya got there, at any rate. *Altruist*, in any morphology, isn't in any user guides or menus...